# wrapping a javascript variable with double quotes

Tags: javascript, string, templates

I've the following code with a string inside a js template literal.

```
`${currentType} ${objProp} = ${value};`
```

I want to wrap the `${value}` with double quotes when it prints. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Instead of repeating myself on each of the multitude of identical answers: simply wrapping the value in quotes is unsafe, as it will make a mess when the value itself contains double quotes.

Comment: @Amadan No it does not fail. I have tested it. If the value itself contains double quotes, those double quotes will be escaped and hence should work fine.

Comment: @Suhas: It did fail, just not with an error. The output is `"hello world = ""hi"";`, which is invalid JavaScript, if you were trying for a programming-language syntax, which seems to be the goal. You'd want to have  `"hello world = "\"hi\"";`, which is not obtained by your method.

Comment: @Amadan: If the variable `value` is intended to be wrap by double quote, it meant to be wrapped by double quote, I really don't see the problem

Comment: @Isaac See the edit on my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
let currentType = "hello";
let objProp = "world";
let value = "hi";
let a = `${currentType} ${objProp} = "${value}";`

console.log(a)
```

Just use the double quote surrounding your `${value}`

**UPDATES:**

Just to try out to prove that it can supports double quoted string as below

```js
let value = '"hi"';
let a = `${value}`;
console.log(a)

let value2 = "\"hi\"";
let a2 = `${value2}`;
console.log(a2)
```

Comment: @Amadan: Do you mean `let value = "\"hi\"";`

Comment: @Amadan: I've also tested with `let value = '"hi"';` none of it failed

Answer (score 5):

```
`${currentType} ${objProp} = ${JSON.stringify(value)};`
```

Using `JSON.stringify` will do the right thing for all JS primitives, quoting strings, and correctly formatting objects and arrays.

**EDIT** because so many of other answerers seem to be missing the point:

```js
let currentType = 'string';
let objProp = 'actor';
let value = 'Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson';

let bad = `${currentType} ${objProp} = "${value}";`
console.log(bad);
// string actor = "Dwayne "The Rock" Johnson";

let good = `${currentType} ${objProp} = ${JSON.stringify(value)};`
console.log(good);
// string actor = "Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson";
```

Comment: Ok I got your point, upvoted. However, OP did not specifically mentioned such requirement and so for that I'll stay neutral on ground

Comment: @Isaac: He did not specifically mention it, but it is kind of obvious by the variable names and the format of the code.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using ES6 string templates, you can use double quotations (`"`) or single quotations (`'`) within the template. Hence this should work:

```
`${currentType} ${objProp} = "${value};"`
```

Comment: No, it does not, because if the string contains double quotes, escape characters will be used and it will not fail

Comment: Where would the escape characters come from?

Comment: When you say the value itself contains double quotes, those double quotes will have to be escaped or how would the code compile?

Answer (score 2):

Just wrapping `${value}` inside double quotes does not seem to be a problem:

```js
var currentType = 11;
var objProp = "test";
var value = 33;

var templateVar = `${currentType} ${objProp} = "${value}";`
console.log(templateVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet....

```js
let val = "1243"
let k = `"${val}"`
console.log(k)
```